# How to make all the elements in a Pandas Dataframe column with the index of groupby column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have dataset where we have user_id, date when order was created, cart - id of a good`s category, was this good reordered or not

It is necessary to bring it to such a form when there will be a new column with indices of order`s number from exact user. For example, the second user only ordered a product from us for the first time (all the products in new indices column will be marked as 1), then it takes some time, and at the end, at the very bottom of the table, new order from this user appears, and all the products in his basket are numbered by index 2, because this is his second order.

And so it is necessary for every order from every user to do

What I did for the current moment:

```
qq0 = pd.DataFrame((df.groupby(['user_id','order_completed_at', 'cart'], 
                               sort = False).count()).groupby(['cart'], sort = False).cumcount()+1)
qq0.columns = ['orders']
qq0[:50]
```

But here I have indexing by counting the time when each product is ordered, without taking to the account a user.
Could you help me?

Comment: It is difficult to answer without a sample dataset. Try to look into something like: `.groupby(["user_id", "order_completed_at"]).cumcount()+ 1` it will count every order from 1 to last order grouped by user_id.

Comment: sorry for not attaching screens, i`m newcomer at stackoverflow, i can`t do it right now =(